# do I need to use nohup and & together

Tags: linux, shell

I see a lot of people are using the following command:

```
nohup ./sendData.sh >logs/send.log 2>&1 &
```

Since the `nohup` has already been used, do I still need to add `&` on the trail?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it will not run in the background and you can only use your shell again once the process is finished.

Comment: I mean do I need to use them together? Can I just use nohup only or & only? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try it with a simpler command, i.e. `nohup sleep 60 &` and fiddle around with it until you see what each element adds to the picture. Good luck.

Comment: Note that there is an arguably "cleaner" alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9646339/572743

Answer (score 19):

[nohup](/questions/tagged/nohup) tells the terminal to not hang up, even when the parent terminal is closed. `&` tells the terminal to send the process to the background. So

```
command &
```

will send the `command` to the background. You can then use the shell to invoke other `commands`. If the terminal is exited, the jobs are killed.

```
nohup command
```

will not send the `command` to the background, but when you close the terminal, the process will live on until it is finished or killed.

```
nohup command &
```

will send the `command` to the background **and** the process will not be killed even when you close the terminal. Usually when using [nohup](/questions/tagged/nohup), one also wants the process to be in the background, that's why you see the combination of [nohup](/questions/tagged/nohup) and `&` more often than not.

Comment: Excuse me for being a nitpick on your otherwise excellent reply. `nohup` doesn't tell the terminal anything, that's more like what e.g. `disown -h` would do. Nohup is a program that ignores the `HUP` signal and that fork-executes its first commandline parameter, forwarding the others. So, technically, the terminal does try to hang up, it's just that nobobdy cares what it has to say.

Comment: @Damon ,i am so confused, because `nohup command` ideally is used to prevent sending hangup signal to its fork-executed command process. but hangup are received when terminal closes, which terminates nohup too. so just `nohup command` not helpful usually because why would that new process receive hangup if terminal not closed