# How to use npm run watch and php artisan serve together through the command prompt?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, laravel-artisan

I enter `npm run watch` first and then then I can't enter `php artisan serve`. Is there a way I can use them in the same command?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [linux - running process background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525188/linux-running-process-background)

Comment: `npm run watch &`

Answer (score 1):

Open two terminals and enter npm run watch into one, and when that's ready run php artisan in the other terminal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, `npm run hot` works correctly with Laravel 8 and Vue 2. I'm using built-in Vue scaffolding of Laravel UI (and not a separate Vue CLI project).

Just use `php artisan serve` to serve your Laravel application and then open a new terminal window and run `npm run hot`. Now the browser output will update automatically when you make changes to your Vue components.

Make sure your `webpack.mix.js` contains the `.vue()` call in its chain.